# 2 substitution variables in a query & execute the second substitution variable first

Tags: mysql, database

I wanted to update the employee's salary by prompting the user to enter the employee id first then update the salary of the particular employee. Is there any possible way of allowing the WHERE clause to execute the substitute parameter first than the SET clause?
[image]

Comment: It appears that you want to SELECT the employee row to get the current name and salary, then after the user changes the salary, UPDATE the employee row.

Comment: sorry i'm still in the beginner stage, do you mean by saving the employee row to a variable and then UPDATE it?

Comment: Yes.  Two variables, one for the name and one for the salary.